# How can I create a generic function that converts a list of ClassA to ClassB, using existing overloaded mapping functions. (C#)

Tags: c#, generics

I have a number of overloaded methods which are used to convert objects from one class to another. e.g.

```
    private ClassB MapClass(ClassA inputClass)
    {
        ClassB outputClass = new ClassB();
        outputClass.PropA = inputClass.PropA;
        outputClass.PropB = inputClass.PropB;
        ...
        return outputClass;
    }

    private ClassD MapClass(ClassC inputClass)
    {
        ...
    }
```

My issue is that sometimes I might have a list of ClassA that I want to convert to a list of ClassB. Is there a way that I can write a generic method which will accept a list of ClassA, call the appropriate conversion function and return a list of ClassB? I could of course simply write an extra conversion method for each which accepts a list, but as there are about 20 such methods I would like to avoid the code repetition if possible.

To clarify, I am trying to do something like:

```
    private List<T1> MapModelList<T1, T2>(List<T2> inputList)
    {
        List<T1> outputList = new List<T1>();

        foreach (T2 input in inputList)
        {
            T1 output = new T1();
            output = MapClass(input);
            outputList.Add(output);
        }

        return outputList;
    }
```

which obviously does not work. Is there a way to make this work, or a better approach perhaps?

Comment: Take a look at Automapper (http://automapper.org/)

Comment: Unless I'm reading your requirements incorrectly, this can be done out of the box via LINQ, e.g. `var listB = listA.Select(item => YOUR_MAPPING_METHOD(item)).ToList();`.

Comment: @decPL You are correct, I hadn't realised this could be done with LINQ. This makes things much simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to pass an argument to the method that was a delegate to an appropriate conversion method.

```
private List<TOutput> MapModelList<TInput, TOutput>(List<TInput> input, Func<TInput, TOutput> mapper)
{
    return input.Select(mapper).ToList();
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var bList = MapModelList(aList, MapClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new instance of T2 with:

```
System.Activator.CreateInstance<T2>()
```

or

just add a new constraint:

```
where T2 : new()
```

or pass in the mapping function as a paraemeter:

```
private List<T1> MapModelList<T1, T2>(List<T2> inputList, Func<T2> map)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method to take a conversion function.

```
private List<T1> MapModelList<T1, T2>(List<T2> inputList, Func<T2, T1> convert) {
    return inputList.Select(i => convert(i)).ToList();
}
```

Also, if you make them all implement the same interface, you only have to write 1 method.

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    PropA { get; set; }
    PropB { get; set; }
}

private T MapClass<T>(ISomeInterface inputClass)
    where T : ISomeInterface, new()
{
    T outputClass = new T();
    outputClass.PropA = inputClass.PropA;
    outputClass.PropB = inputClass.PropB;
    ...
    return outputClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual void Map<T>(T obj)
    {
        // Override in specific class
        //Use PropertyInfo to map the properties of the class
    }
}

public class MyFirstClass : MyBaseClass
{
}

public class MySecondClass : MyBaseClass
{

}

public class MyClassFactory
{
    public T CreateMyClass<T>() where T : MyBaseClass, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public List<T1> MapClass<T1, T2>(List<T2> inputList) where T1 : MyBaseClass, new()
    {
        List<T1> outputList = new List<T1>();

        foreach (T2 input in inputList)
        {
            T1 output = CreateMyClass<T1>();
            output.Map(input);
            outputList.Add(output);
        }

        return outputList;
    }
}
```

you can try something like this.

And can be used is Main as

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyFirstClass> firstClasses = new List<MyFirstClass>();
        MyFirstClass obj1 = new MyFirstClass();
        MyFirstClass obj2 = new MyFirstClass();
        MyFirstClass obj3 = new MyFirstClass();
        MyFirstClass obj4 = new MyFirstClass();

        firstClasses.Add(obj1);
        firstClasses.Add(obj2);
        firstClasses.Add(obj3);
        firstClasses.Add(obj4);

        var secondClasses = new MyClassFactory().MapClass<MySecondClass, MyFirstClass>(firstClasses);
    }
}
```